# What should be the appropriate pseudo-code of the following maze?

Tags: pseudocode, maze

[image: From o> reach E]

Puzzle is: `From o> reach E`.

I'm trying to solve the following maze with the help of the choices on the left but I'm not able to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve *that* particular maze is fairly simple, consisting of four instances of `move forward`, a `turn right`, five more `move forward` steps, another `turn right`, and so on.

However, assuming you're looking for a more general solution, you can often solve a maze by hugging one side (left or right, it rarely matters).

Such an algorithm can be easily built up from the steps provided to first find both keys (ignoring doors) then, once that's done, keep going with the same scheme (hug one wall), detecting and opening the doors as they become available.

Comment: The simulation doesnt go further after acquiring the second key, could you please provide a logical ordering of the choices on the left ?

Comment: Vishal, the general idea behind SO is that we help you solve your problems, not do your classwork for you - the latter is actually damaging to your abilities long term. If you'd like to post what you've currently tried, we can offer more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(start != end) do
move forward
if(Right_Turn_Available) then
Turn Right
if(Red_Key_Found) then
Unlock Red Lock
else if(Blue_Key_Found) then
Unlock Blue Lock
end-if
end-if
end-while
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].